# Global form of flavour symmetry groups in gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, symmetry, gauge-theory, topology

How do we work out the global nature of a flavour symmetry group? To be concrete, consider the simplest example of QED, preferably in D dimensions, with $N$ flavours of fermions with Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu D_\mu +m)\psi,$$

where $D$ is the gauge covariant derivative, and $\psi$ is in the defining rep of $U(N)$. Naïvely, this Lagrangian is invariant under $U(N)$, but one has to quotient out the center $U(1)$ as these correspond to global gauge transformations, and then one obtains $U(N)/U(1)$, which is isomorphic to $SU(N)/\mathbb{Z}_N$ (cf [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397274/showing-un-zun-sun-zsun), for instance). Isn’t this the largest possible flavour group in this theory? Why do many references assume at the outset that the flavour group is $SU(N)$?

Operators in the QFT will organize into irreps of this symmetry, which in general depend on the global nature of the group. Is there any general way of determining what this is? If not, are there examples where it is known beyond doubt?

Comment: $\uparrow$ QED??

Comment: You need to rewrite your question clearly. The U(1) is baryon number. Why do your bother with covariant derivatives of U(1) of EM? are you planning to gauge the flavor group, a highly deprecated stunt? In short, what is your question, really?

Comment: The flavour group is not gauged. As I stated, flavour rotations are supposed to be a symmetry. The Lagrangian as written is compatible with this group being U(N), or SU(N), or some discrete quotients of these groups. I want to know if there is a general way, or explicit examples, in which one can fully determine the global form of this symmetry group.

Comment: To clarify, the Lagrangian in the question in D=3 with N=4 (edit; and m=0) describes a Dirac spin liquid. We generally call such a theory “compact QED3” (not my nomenclature, but one I agree with). The U(1) gauge field is emergent. The four flavours of relativistic fermions arise from linearizing lattice fermions with spin at two Dirac nodes in a given lattice model. Perhaps a condmat or quantum spin liquid tag should be added, but I thought the question general to QFT.

Comment: If this is really QED, i.e. the gauge group is $\mathrm{U}(1)$, then it is simply $N$ non-interacting copies of QED. The global symmetry group is just rotations between these theories, so it's $\mathrm{U}(N)$. No such rotation can compensated by a (rigid) gauge transformation, so this is the full global symmetry. If you mixed your words and meant QCD, then maybe you wanted to ask what is the global form of the gauge group?